# How to add TypeScript typings for the following library pattern?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a JavaScript library (let's call it `foo`) which, simplified, looks somewhat like this:

```
class Foo {
  static frob(cb) {
    const result = 'frobbed';
    if (cb) return cb(result);
    return Promise.resolve(result);
  } 
}

module.exports = Foo;
```

In my `index.d.ts` I put the following:

```
type FrobCallback = (result: string) => void;
type FrobPromise = Promise<string>;
type FrobReturnType = FrobPromise | void;

declare class Foo {
  static frob(callback: (result: string) => void): FrobReturnType;
}

export = Foo;
```

The problem is that whoever now consumes the library, if they want to use the promise based version must cast to `FrobPromise` and have that type available to them to avoid repeating `Promise<string>`.

I cannot say `export type FrobPromise = Promise<string>`, because that will trigger *TS2093: An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements* error message.

Therefore, I had to resort to creating another file, let's call it `types.d.ts`, which exports `FrobPromise` and I can finally use my library like this:

```
import Foo = require('foo');
import { FrobPromise } from 'foo/types';

(Foo.frob() as FrobPromise).then(result => console.log(result.length);
```

Is there some way to achieve a nicer notation for the above statements above? It seems like there should be a more elegant solution to the problem I am describing. I do not have control over `foo` except for adding typings.

Comment: Overloads? [Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads)

Comment: That's a good idea and it helps somewhat. However, in my case the return type is actually this: `void | Promise<IFoo> | Promise<IBar>`. So in the end I don't think I can avoid casting. I don't see how I can do that without `import`ing the appropriate type :-(

Comment: Maybe there could be a way around that using generics.

Comment: If there is no way to tell from the parameters what is returned, sounds like you are right - though if that's the case it may be worth splitting that method up. (Or writing a wrapper as you don't have control of the source)

Comment: Solved one use case nicely. However there is other way the lib can be used. You can create an instance and give it a strategy (a function), which will determine what `get` instance method returns. And for that I really cannot see how to get away without exporting those types in order to make `Foo` generic. But I think I can live with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function which either takes a callback or returns a promise can be handled nicely using overloading:

```
declare class Foo {
  static frob(callback: (result: string) => void): void;
  static frob(): Promise<string>;
}
```

In other more complicated situations there might be no better solution than generics and exported types as outlined in the question.